# Get connection IP of WebSocket connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, ip

Once I've opened a web socket like so:

```
m_ws = new WebSocket(127.0.0.1);
```

Is it possible to get the IP that was just used to open? Something like `m_ws._websocket.address`?

I've seen numerous examples but none of them worked as I think they apply to WebSocketServer instances.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213590/get-ip-address-from-websocket-in-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use the [`ws` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)?

If you use `ws` to get IP Connection :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
  const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
});
```

Comment: We're not starting web socket server. We are connecting to an existing web socket connection that is running on localhost.

Comment: Can I find out the remoteAddress when just using new WebSocket?

Comment: You can use my solution including localhost. 
When you start server on localhost, that is server and you are both client and server, so you can find ip completely.